# JPA- dynamically create entity manager with JTA transaction type

Tags: jpa, jta, entitymanager

I have few databases with the same tables structure, each separate for different language. I use JPA with JTA transaction type. I'd like to create dynamically new connection to database (from appliction level) when I add new language (new database). I know how to create new entity manager but only for RESOURCES_LOCAL transaciton type. Is it possible with JTA?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a design flaw that makes everything look more complicated than it is. If you have the choice, the best thing to do, although it requires some work, is to internationalize your database. Shortly, add a "language" column where appropriate and just have one database with everything. When you select the bits you're interested in for one language, just add that language restriction to your where clause.

What you are asking would be quite complicated to implement and maintain.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I know the design of this application is complicated but it already exists. I have no permission to change it so I have to find a way to solve this issue anyway.

Comment: you could simulate a better design by using views. I'd do all I can to change the design, though ;-)